# How to detect culture by IP address

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, localization

I need to customize my website for every region and set default culture for loading site .  In second step if users wanted they can change language and culture by selecting from a list (I implemented it by setting cookie).

For example I want , a person in Germany see site with setting culture to "de-DE" automatically, in Spain set "es-ES" for culture and for other countries set "en-US" for DefaultRequestCulture.
Actually  I want to load website with nearest culture for users by detecting their IP Address or something like this at the first time.

```
var options = new RequestLocalizationOptions()
            {
                //DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US"),
                SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
                SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures,
                RequestCultureProviders = new List<IRequestCultureProvider>()
                {
                    new QueryStringRequestCultureProvider(),
                    new CookieRequestCultureProvider()
                }
            };
app.UseRequestLocalization(options);
```

Is it needs IP range and how can I implement it in .net core ?

Comment: You'll need a database or service that can map IP address ranges to geographic locations. As a side note: I hate sites that do this. Because I'm in Japan, some sites like GoDaddy throw me into the Japanese version for everything, even the help section, and some make it very difficult to get back to the English version. If possible, I'd suggest obeying the browser's language choices (as sent via the Accept-Language header).

Comment: If I set my preferred language to Spanish as a German, I'm expecting Spanish if your site supports it, not German

Comment: Please: do not do it. Respect your users! Browser will give you the user preferences (and language, in form of de_DE).

Answer (score 3):

IP address is not a reliable option for culture detection;

- IP’s are dynamic and the ip range for each country may change from time to time.
- Being in a specific country doesn’t mean you speak its language.

It is better to use AccptedLanguageHeaderRequestCultureProvider, because it is more relevant to what could be the user is using.

See this answer for more details:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67086730/5519026